# What is the reward for returning robbery money?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just stopped a robbery random event (clothing store) and recovered the money, $2000. A pop-up says that I can keep the money or return it for a reward. What is the reward, and does it differ between the type of store robbed? I know the events are random, but are the rewards/amounts predictable depending on the type of store robbed?

Comment: My experience has been really random with these. Grab $2k, get a $200 reward... Return a bike, get $100k in stock. It seems pretty random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These events in particular are less random as they include a cutscene - there are only two shop robbery random events:

- The Suburban clothing store in Prosperity Street Promenade, Del Perro
- The Bon Mulét hair salon in Eastbourne Way, Rockford Hills

Both of these give a **$2,000 reward** if the money is not returned.

Returning the money to:

- Suburban: **25% discount on next purchase**
- Bon Mulét: **No reward given**

Answer (score 0):

If you want advice, keep the money, just if an Indian sounding lady's car gets hijacked, or a guys push bike gets stolen, return these items, as a huge reward is privately given.

The guy with the bike gives I think $100000 in shares which you can sell immediately.